# IronPython based web-service

Tags: web-services, iis, ironpython, distribution, json-rpc

I want to use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) to develop the logic behind a [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/) web-service project.

My questions are:

- Can I develop without using Visual Studio?
- What build system should I use (favorably not XML-based)?
- How does deployment under IIS work (what exactly do I need to distribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

- Can I develop without using Visual Studio?

  Absolutely all of the .NET compilers can be run from the command line.

  Here's a list of tools and IDE's for working with IronPython:

  > [Tools and IDEs Working with IronPython](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/tools-and-ides.shtml)
- What build system should I use (favorably not XML-based)?

  If I was doing this then I'd probably use [`make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), but then I'm old fashioned
- How does deployment under IIS work (what exactly do I need to distribute)?

  If your IronPython application has dependencies on any non-standard .NET Framework libraries then you'll probably need them in your `/bin` folder. But other than that deployment should just be a plain old XCOPY job.

**Updated:**

*Also I would like to know what kind of application I need to create: do I have to stick with CGI using IronPython or are there alternatives?*

Just treat IronPython as you would C# or VB.NET. There's a sample IronPython ASP.NET project here:

> [ASP.NET Dynamic Language Support](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20Language%20Support)
>
> [ASP.NET IronPython Binaries and Examples](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/17613#DownloadId=69511)

Scott Guthrie wrote up an article on IronPython + ASP.NET a few years back:

> [IronPython for ASP.NET CTP](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/16/ironpython-for-asp-net-ctp.aspx)

If you can do it in C# or VB.NET then you can do it in IronPython.

Miscellaneous links:

> [IronPython Cookbook](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Main_Page)
>
> [Voidspace - author of IronPython in Action](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Also I would like to know what kind of application I need to create: do I have to stick with CGI using IronPython or are there alternatives?